# Como quitar varias filas en varios dataframe de pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Tengo un archivo de excel con 9 hojas, todas ellas lucen de la siguiente forma:

```
|Rank| Country         | All    | Agr    |Ind  |Dom   |
-------------------------------------------------------
|1   |Argentina        |2       |3       |1    |5     |
|4   |Chile            |3       |3       |4    |3     |
|3   |Colombia         |1       |2       |1    |4     |
|4   |Mexico           |3       |5       |4    |2     |
|3   |Panama           |2       |1       |5    |4     |
|2   |Peru             |3       |3       |4    |2     |
```

De todas ellas quiero quitar las mismas filas, lo que hice fue crear una lista con las filas que quiero quitar, agrupando por la columna Country :

```
paises = ["Colombia", "Peru", "Chile"]
```

y también cree una lista con todos los dataframes:

```
datafms = [df1, df2, df3, df4]
```

y luego, esta línea de código para eliminar en todos las filas que tuvieran alguno de los elementos de la lista `paises` en la columna `Country`:

```
for df in datafms:
    df = df.drop(labels=paises, axis=0, inplace=False)
```

Pero me dice que no encuentra el elemento ["Colombia", "Peru", "Chile"].

Pueden ayudarme?

Answer (score 1):

En vez de eliminarlos, puedes directamente ignorar las filas que contengan cierto valor, es decir, necesitas que tu *DataFrame* muestre todos los paises menos los que se encuentran en `paises`.

Para ello solo es necesario modificar un poquito tu código:

```
new_list = []
for df in datafms:
    
    new_list.append(df[~df['Country'].isin(paises)])
```

- [DataFrame.isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) nos dirá si el registro se encuentra en nuestro `DataFrame` (*True*) y si no se encuentra (*False*)
- `~` convierte `True` en `False` y viceversa.

**Para ver solos los registros de tu lista de `paises`**:

Solamente hay que quitar `~`. Ya que necesitamos los valores en los que devolverá *True*.

```
new_list = []
for df in datafms:
    
    new_list.append(df[df['Country'].isin(paises)])
```

Ahora en `new_list` están los dfs reducidos.

Sí deseas acceder a cada uno de los dfs, tan solo puedes usar el indice de la *lista*.
Ej : `new_list[0]`

Y si necesitas que todo sea un *DataFrame*, en vez de definir una lista, definimos un *DataFrame* vacio:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame([])
for df in datafms:

    new_df = new_df.append(df[df['Country'].isin(paises)])
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, al contrario, me equivoqué formulando la pregunta, lo que necesito es que solo me muestre solo los paises que están en la lista. Pero necesito que los elimine de mi data frame. Puedes ayudarme?

Comment: Acabo de editar la respuesta

Comment: Muchas gracias. En esencia, sí hizo lo que necesitaba, el problema es que quedó como una lista, y yo necesito que sea un dataframes como los otros... Me puedes ayudar otra vez?

Comment: Checa ahora la edición